# validation message for fields inside a4j:repeat

Tags: validation, jsf, loops

I am having issues to display the validation message set using validatorMessage attribute for a component inside a4j:repeat.

Here is the code :

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{array}" var="value">

   <h:inputText id="someId" validatorMessage="custom message" required="true" value="#{someValue}">
   <h:message for="someId" />
</a4j:repeat>
```

Validation is working but printing some message with long id. I guess it is using the generated id. 
ie
j_id333049330_13d9ed7d:j_id333049330_13d9ef4c:0:someId: Validation Error: Value is required.

It is not possible to put EL inside id attribute.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the label part of the validation message. This is normally to be set by `<h:inputText label>`, but when it's absent, then indeed by default the component's client ID will be used.

Just manually set the label:

```
<h:inputText ... label="Some ID" />
```

Comment: Hi Balus,

i added label attribute and the ugly id is gone. But still the validation msg I defined using validatorMessage attribute is not showing up. JSF defined msg is showing up. Better than before , but still not what I wanted. 

Thanks,
Ravi